# default vs custom using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework

I've got a table of default templates. It's global to all users. If a user has no custom template, I want to pull the default. If a user decides to customize the template it should be saved in a customtemplates table - as opposed to the globaltempaltes table. 
the custom table has all the globaltemplates fields plus a userid and an id relating to which global it is replacing.

To flesh this out a bit more, lets say there are 3 templates, and a user wants to customize template 2 only. I would normaly pull the whole globaltemplates table and whatever relates to the user in the customtemplates table. Then, in the class property I'd do something in the get like this:

```
MyTemplateA
get { return customtemplates.A ?? globaltemplates.A; }
```

Can I do this using straight ef4/linq without poco?
Would a partial class with some additional properties like the get above work?

Since i'm always editing only the customtemplates table (add/edit/delete) it doesn't matter which version of the template I pull. I guess it could get hairy figuring out if it's an insert or an update.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it will not work as you expect because EF closely relates entity to table. You cannot have single entity mapped to two tables except very special situations like splitting or inheritance.

So if you have `Template` entity it can be mapped only to single table but you have two. What you can do is to use TPC inheritance where `Template` will be a base entity mapped to `GlobalTemplates` table and `UserTemplate` will be derived entity mapped to `UserTemplates` table. TPC (table per concrete type) is type of inheritance where table for derived entity contains all columns from table for parent entity.

But inheritance still has a few problems for your scenario:

- `Template` is editable - if you want to have it read only you must correctly handle it in your application logic. Any changes to attached `Template` instance will be saved when you call `SaveChanges` on the context.
- When you load `Template` you cannot directly convert it to `UserTemplate` to make it user specific. You must create new instance of `UserTemplate` and copy properties from `Template` to the newly created instance.

Comment: Could this be solved another way then? What about upon user creation, the global templates being copied to the user templates table, then I would only be dealing with one object. More overhead but a simpler object. I imagine whatever pattern i'm conveying here isn't that rare a case.

Comment: If you are happy with having copy of each template for each user even if user doesn't want to make changes that would be good way to go.